# Clone and setup Repository from Bit Bucket to XCode

Tags: xcode, react-native, bitbucket

joined a new organisation. Never worked on react native repositories before.

I need a quick help on how to clone a React Native repository from bit bucket to Xcode and setup to work only on iOS module.

I have downloaded the repository and open the iOS Folder and opened projectname.xcworkspace file. It opened my project but so many files are missing. So I assume that it is not the right way to do. Please help.

Comment: I think you are looking for instructions on how to open a project in xcode: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/CreatingProjects.html

Comment: Sorry, That is not what I meant. I have been working on native iOS app for some time now. But what I need is how to clone a bitbucket repository which is a react native app source code in xcode and work on iOS module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you didn't use command of `npm install` or `yarn install` then after completed the above command you need to use `cd ios`(Go to ios directory) and `pod install` then you should open your projectname.xcworkspace file.

if you have package-lock.json then use npm install and if you have yarn.lock then use yarn install command.

Comment: Where should I run npm install. Should it be in React Native directory folder?

Comment: Yes, In the same directory where you have package.json file.

Comment: @Unwind Did you fix you issue?

Comment: Yeah but I did it some other way which is almost what you said but I made some mistakes while cloning. So what I did is, I deleted my project folder and installed GitHub desktop and then cloned the repository from remote to my machine with GitHub desktop and then switched to the working dev branch. From there you can go to "GitHub Desktop>Repository>Open in Terminal" and then run the command `npm run run-ios` which is written in the package.json file. Thats it now I can open up my somename.xcworkspace and run it..

Comment: @Unwind Please approve the question if it helped. Thanks

Comment: I accepted the answer mate. Didn't have enough rep to upvote. Thanks for the help btw.